# Number Theory proving primes and quadratic reciprocity

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Hey so this problem came up in our group, but can't seem to crack it.

If p>5 is a prime number, then show that at least one of 2,5, or 10 is a quadratic residue. Along the same lines, suppose p is an odd prime and b is the smallest positive quadratic nonresidue mod p. Prove that b is prime.

we first showed the cases for quadratic residue.

2^2=x(mod p>5) 
5^2 = x(mod p >5)
10^2 = x(mod p >5)

we think we proved that much by showing a table that any square divided by any prime greater than 5. However, as you can see it has its weak assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

Product of two quadratic nonresidues is a quadratic residue.

Two times five is ten.

Comment: And now the answer for the second question should become obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic of even order, its subgroup of squares has index $2$.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with the Legendre symbol then here's a way to see it. If either $\left( \frac{2}{p} \right)=1$ or $\left( \frac{5}{p} \right)=1$, then we're done. So suppose $\left( \frac{2}{p} \right)=-1$ and $\left( \frac{5}{p} \right)=-1$. Then $\left( \frac{10}{p} \right)= \left( \frac{2}{p} \right) \left( \frac{5}{p} \right)=1$.